# Excel 2019 Transpose: Transposing multiple columns Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019, transpose

I have an excel sheet with three columns: Country, Year and Fuel consumption per capita.

Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

The country column has data for all worldwide countries. The year range for each country is from 1965 to 2021. I'm trying to transpose the data in such a way that there's just one row for each country and a separate column for every year and its associated fuel consumption. Could anyone please help me with that?

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand you to do Insert / Table on your dataset. Then your dataset will have a name, and if you add data, the name will cover the extra data. (The table coverage is shown by half the lines colored).

Then Insert / Pivot Table. On the right, you have the different fields you can drag on drop below (Country on rows, year on columns, Fossil fuel on value).